# how to join 2 tables , check if each element of 'em exist in the 3 table and represent it as a number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these 3 tables:
1.movies

```
movie_id  title
  1     Toy Story (1995)
  2     Jumanji (1995)
  3     Grumpier Old Men (1995)
```

2.genres

```
 genre_id   genre
    1      Action
    2      Adventure
    3      Animation
```

3.movies_genre

```
 m_g_id  movie_id   genre_id
      1     1       2
      2     2       1
      3     2       2
      4     3       1
      5     3       2
      6     3       3
```

i'm looking for this: **where value=1 if a movie with a specific genre exist in movies_genre else value=1**

```
movie_id    genre     value
   1        Action     0
   1        Adventure  1
   1        Animation  0
   2        Action     1
   2        Adventure  1
   2        Animation  0
   3        Action     1
   3        Adventure  1
   3        Animation  0
```

in order to join each element of ***movies*** with all elements of ***gender*** i use the query below but i don't know how to get the specific value ?

```
SELECT movie_id,genre
FROM movies, genres 
Order by movie_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `cross join` with an `outer join`.  Then you can use a `case` statement to get the `value`:

```
select m.movie_id,
  g.genre_id, 
  case when mg.m_g_id is null then 0 else 1 end 
from movies m 
  cross join genres g 
  left join movies_genre mg on m.movie_id = mg.movie_id 
                           and g.genre_id = mg.genre_id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03251/1)